# Solution of second order differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation:

$$u''(x) = \lambda \ u(x), \ \ \ 0 <x < \pi$$

I want to find solutions $u_1, u_2$ such that the following data are satisfied:

$$u_1(0) = 0, \ \ u_1'(0) = 1; \ \ \ u_2(\pi) = 0, \ u_2'(\pi) = 1  $$

We may allow $u_1, u_2, \lambda$ to be complex valued. This seems to me like a 2nd order ODE with constant coefficients with general solution:

$$y = c\exp(x\sqrt{\lambda} ) + d\exp(-x\sqrt{\lambda} )$$

This cannot be the case otherwise the solution would only be the trivial one. Any suggestions, solutions, hints will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: That's an awful lot of "initial" conditions for a second order equation!

Comment: It's under the chapter of boundary-value problems, if this helps. Any suggestions at all?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think he's looking for two solutions, one with initial conditions for $u_1$ and another for initial conditions specified as $u_2$.  That said, the initial conditions $f(0) = c_1$, $f'(0) = c_2$ and $f''(x) = \lambda f(x)$ for all $x$ has only one solution by a general existence-uniqueness theorem.

Comment: Still though, there are way to many conditions.

Comment: Not really.  The existence-uniqueness theorem guarantees the existence of at least one solution satisfying the differential equation and two initial conditions and the fact that that solution is unique.

Comment: The problem is as follows. $u_1 = c_1\exp({x\lambda})$ and I am supposed to use the give conditions on this function. Wouldn't this force $c_1 = 0$?

Comment: I took the question to mean that $u$ is a vector with components $u_1$ and $u_2$.

Comment: You might want to look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320152/determine-the-eigenvalues-and-corresponding-eigenfunctions-if-phi-satisfies/320156#320156

Answer (score 2):

If $\lambda<0$ then we denote $-\lambda=w^2$ then the general solution is
$$y=c\cos(wx)+d\sin(wx).$$
With $u_1(0)=0$ we have $c=0$ and $u'_1(0)=1$ gives $d=\frac{1}{w}$.

For $u_2$ we must solve the system:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
c\cos(w\pi)+d\sin(w\pi)&=0\\
-cw\sin(w\pi)+dw\cos(w\pi)&=1\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: That's the way to do it.

Comment: What happens though when $\lambda > 0$?

Comment: If $\lambda>0$ then the solution is expressed with exponantial function so if it vanishes at a point it vanishes everywhere.

Comment: Nice! That was my thought too! Thanks for all the help! All the best!